# jQuery syntax for changing the value of a table cell

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table where every row has a unique id.
The last table cell has class="status" where I want to show the user the result of their action.

In my $.ajax call, I have:

```
        ,success: function(result){
            $('tr#'+result).td('.status').text('Updated');
        };
```

result is the id of the row that was updated.

It's just throwing an error message that says $( and that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no method named `.td()`. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
$('tr#' + result + ' td.status').text('Updated');
```

Also make sure that `result` has valid value.

```
console.log(result);
```

You didn't post whole code, but it looks like parse error – the code should probably end with `});`, not `};`.

Comment: Thanks Yaggo!  I guess I've been looking at this #js too long today.

Comment: Yeah, that happens sometimes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ancestory/descendant relationships can be put in a single $ call like this:

```
$('tr#' + result + ' td.status').text('Updated');
```

Just remember to put a space between the ancestor and child. Example output:

```
$('tr#row10 td.status').text('Updated');
```

Additionally, an ID should only be sued once, so you could probably omit the initial tr, like:

```
$('#' + result + ' td.status').text('Updated');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/